# how can i break the line in JOptionpane message box

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2005, ant

```
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
    importPackage(javax.swing);
    importPackage(java.lang);
    System.out.println("Hello from JavaScript!");
    var optionPane = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,'Deployment instruction = ' + Deployment_Instrution);
    ]]>
    </script>
```

here `Deployment_Instruction` is variable in which i am storing the output of sql select query. the output of sql select query length is too much big so the size of JOptionpane message box is also going bigger. for this i want to break the big line in message box.
how can i do this.pls help[ me out asap.
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have to break the line by inserting newlines where appropriate.  For a simple application like this it might do to just have a basic function that breaks on spaces once a line reaches the maximum length that you want.

Something like:

```
var boxText = wrapLines( 30, Deployment_Instruction );
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, boxText );
```

Here the maximum length would be 30 characters.  With the wrapLines function being:

```
function wrapLines(max, text)
{
    max--;
    text = "" + text;
    var newText = "";
    var lineLength = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        var c = text.substring(i, i+1);
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            newText += c;
            lineLength = 1;
        }
        else if (c == ' ' && lineLength >= max)
        {
            newText += '\n';
            lineLength = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            newText += c;
            lineLength++;
        }
    }
    return (newText);
}
```

Note that this will give a 'ragged' right edge, so if there is a very long word at the end of a line it may not be satisfactory.

By the way your variable name is missing a letter 'c' - *Instru?tion*.

Comment: it's working but for `The new entry should be as folows credit terms are equlent to  validacreditterms entry of  ICTSConfigData.plist  file.    **********<CSValidCreditTerm_ARRAY_><CSValidCreditTerm>DOCLC</CSValidCreditTerm><CSValidCreditTerm>PARTPREP</CSValidCreditTerm><CSValidCreditTerm>OPEN</CSValidCreditTerm><CSValidCreditTerm>SBLC</CSValidCreditTerm></CSValidCreditTerm_ARRAY_>` line it's printing like 
`in 1 line->The new entry should be as folows`
`in 2 line->credit terms are equlent to`
`in 3 line->validacreditterms entry of  ICTSConfigData.plist`
`in 4 line->rest all`

Comment: That looks a bit trickier than a simple sentence or two of text.  The problem is that you don't have any spaces to break on in the XML.  Perhaps it would be better to get the formatting included in the stored message.  Or you could try modifying the wrapLines function to maybe split on spaces or `>` characters or something similar - but that's likely to b very imperfect.  If you need to 'pretty print' XML then there may be something out there.